# Jquery ajax call inside script which is loaded from another domain

Tags: jquery, ajax

OK, I know about same domain policy!, and jquery can call it if we use jsonP.

But My problem is little different.

1. Browsers would not allow to call content from another domain because of "Same domain policy". OK fine.
2. But, It should allow to call ajax from where the script is loaded. right?

for example, I am including a script (my-script.js) from ajax.example.com into 
example.com/index.html

> <script src="/jquery.js"></script> 
>   <script src="//ajax.example.com/my-script.js"></script>

so, I can call ajax to ajax.example.com with in my-script.js, right?

But I am using jquery object to call ajax!. So, even I am calling ajax from my-script.js, it is not working as expected. I am sure it is because jquery object is actually created from main domain,

I can use jsonP here, But I wanted to know, is there any solution to call to ajax.example.com from my-script.js via jquery!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not going to work. Where the script is hosted makes no difference to whether AJAX calls are considered cross-domain or not. Only the current domain counts.

Comment: I think you understand it wrongly. If what you said is true, None of the social plugins, like/share buttons, google analytics may work. make sense?

Comment: No. The social plugins go around the same origin policy with other techniques. The server might be set up to allow cross-origin requests, they use JSONP, or they just don't make cross-origin AJAX requests.